# Invalid OAuth2 token in GAE/GWT java app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, oauth-2.0

I am developing an GWT/GAE java application which

1. simply gets the users location via GWT geolocation implementation (works very well)
2. on button click should write the latitude, longitude and accuracy into a Google spreadsheet

When I click on the "save to spreadsheet" button, I am getting the following error messages in my eclipse console:

```
04.09.2012 16:44:01 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse
WARNUNG: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub realm="https://www.google.com/accounts//AuthSubRequest"}
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: OK
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: Stateless token parent not found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: Stateless token parent not found</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
at com.cloudpilots.locator.server.GSpreadsheetServiceImpl.insertRow(GSpreadsheetServiceImpl.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

So it has to be a problem with the credential/token.

Here is the server-side RPC service code:

```
public class GSpreadsheetServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GSpreadsheetService {

    @Override
    public void insertRow(String latitude, String longitude, String accuracy) {

        try {
            String userId = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getUserId();
            Credential credential = OAuth2Utils.initializeFlow().loadCredential(userId);

            SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Locator-v1");

            service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

            // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
            URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

            // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
                SpreadsheetFeed.class);
            List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

            // TODO: Choose a spreadsheet more intelligently based on your
            // app's needs.
            SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
            for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheetEntry : spreadsheets) {
                if (spreadsheetEntry.getKey() == "MY_SPREADSHEET_KEY") {
                    spreadsheet = spreadsheetEntry;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
            // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
            // app's needs.
            WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
                spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
            List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
            WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

            // Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
            URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
            ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

            // Create a local representation of the new row.
            ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
            row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Latitude", latitude);
            row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Longitude", longitude);
            row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Accuracy", accuracy);

            // Send the new row to the API for insertion.
            row = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the OAuth2Utils class:

```
public class OAuth2Utils {
    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    static String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) {
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
        url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
        return url.build();
    }

    static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
        return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                JSON_FACTORY, "MY_CLIENT_ID",
                "MY_KEY",
                Collections.singleton("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"))
                .setCredentialStore(new AppEngineCredentialStore())
                .setAccessType("offline").build();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Best regards,

Juri Wiens

Answer (score 1):

This way works:

1) use Google drive DrEdit example for OAuth https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java

Note: you need to add refresh token, I found adding it was not hard to do.

2) Connect like this:

```
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("cellmaster-v0.2");

    // Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)
    service.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);


    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = getSpreadsheetUrl(spreadsheetKey);
    spreadsheet = service.getEntry 
            (SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
```

I looked at lots of examples. It took me a few days to find this solution.

Comment: link is broken can you please help me out

Comment: https://github.com/googledrive/dredit  Hope it helps, is very old now, maybe look for something more recent.